# Callback runs first? - learnyounode juggling

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can someone help me understand why my solution does not work? It seems like the callback function is running before the juggle function is finished.

My code works fine if I remove the comments. It's just that I don't understand why the log function does not get called after the juggle function is finished. That is how callbacks are supposed to work right?

Thanks in advance :)

```js
var http = require('http')
links = process.argv.slice(2)
var contents = []
//var cbacks = 0

function juggle(callback) {
    links.forEach(function(link, i, links) {
        http.get(link, function(response) {
            response.setEncoding("utf8")
            var str = ""
            response.on("data", function(data) {
                str = str.concat(data)
            })
            response.on("end", function(){
                contents[i] = str
                //cbacks++
                //if(cbacks === 3) {
                //  callback()
                //}
            })
        })
    })
    callback()
}

function log() {
    contents.forEach(function(content, i, contents) {
        console.log(contents[i])
    })
}

juggle(log)
```

Comment: The `callback` function runs before the callback of the `http.get` - because the `http.get` is an async call.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much! Can't believe I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have global scope which is what I would use to actually juggle the requests.

When each link gets registered to an `EventEmitter`, you can store it inside of a map.

```
var link_map = {};
var request_counter = 0;

links.forEach( function (link, index) {
    link_map[link] = '';
...
```

then in your requests you can append data from a specific request

```
 response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    link_map[link] += chunk.toString();
...
```

and finally at each end, check if all requests have finished

```
response.on('end', function () {
    request_counter += 1;
    if ( links.length === request_counter ) {
        // do your logging stuff here and you have all
        // the data that you need inside link_map
...
```

the `link` variable inside of the anonymous function declared in the `forEach` is stored for that closure. So each time that the `'data'` event is emitted, the `link` variable is going to refer to the request for a specific link that was registered to the callback. That is why I chose to use a map data structure and map specific data to each link which we are using as a key.

EventEmitters and callbacks can get kind of harry if you are unfamiliar with them. Keep practicing though and it will eventually become easier.

And using an array as you did is not incorrect or anything, I just prefer to use Objects with key => value pairs when I can.

**RUN THIS CODE** on your machine to see it in action.

```
const http = require('http');

var links = [
        'http://www.google.com',
        'http://www.example.com',
        'http://www.yahoo.com'
];
var link_map = {};
var request_counter = 0;

links.forEach( function (link, index) {
    link_map[link] = '';

    http.get(link, function(response) {
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            link_map[link] += chunk.toString();
        });

        response.on('end', function () {
            request_counter += 1;
            if ( links.length === request_counter ) {
                links.forEach( function(link) {
                    require('fs').writeFileSync(link.split('//')[1],link_map[link]);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You can see an output of files from links in the parent directory.

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time to explain! Dictionaries would be much efficient indeed.

Answer (score 1):

`http.get` is asynchronous.  `forEach` is executed against your links  which calls `http.get`, which registers a connection to be processed.  It doesn't actually complete the connection/request.

if you need to execute the callback when all the `forEach` functions complete you could use a library like `async` to accomplish it.

`async` supports a forEach method.  Using `async`, the first param to `forEach` would take an additional `callback` function which should be called to denote item processing has been finished.  You could place that callback in the `response.on('end')` callback.  When all of those callbacks have been called, or when an error has occurred `async.forEach` will execute the onComplete callback you provide to it as the 3rd parameter, accomplishing your goal.

Comment: If you truly want to learn how to juggle asynchronous requests and functions in Javascript then I wouldn't start by using async. Just my advice, you don't have to take it OP.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was indeed trying to avoid using async and learn juggling the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't wait for http response and call callback function immediately. At this point of code `contents` array is empty.

Comment: I wouldn't use the term wait when dealing with callbacks and asynchronous requests in node/javascript. Nothing is really "waiting"... Events are registered and events are emitted.. etc. It might seem like a minute detail but syntax is important! We are linguists after all...